# Python pickle's data can't update in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label, pickle

here's a part of my code from recent game i've try to make

i'm confused about the data loaded from [pickle] cannot apply to the Label in [tkinter]

it works when i'm saving and loading the data

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle

Prvs_controll = [3,3,3,3,3]
Prvs_size = [1,1,1,1,1]
GameData= [Prvs_controll, Prvs_size]

class MainGame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        global canvas
        self.parent.title('PythonEuropaGame')
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        tkframe = Frame(self)
        canvas = Canvas(self)
        canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        canvas.update()

def save():
    global GameData
    with open('Save_01.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(GameData, handle)
        print(GameData)
def load():
    global canvas
    global GameData
    with open('Save_01.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
        GameData = pickle.load(handle)
        Label_size_b.configure(text = Prvs_size[0])
        print(GameData)

def change_controll():
    global GameData
    GameData[0] = [9,9,9,9,9]

def change_size():
    global GameData
    GameData[1][0] += 150
    Label_size_b.configure(text = Prvs_size[0])

root = Tk()
ex = MainGame(root)
root.geometry('900x650')

Label_size_a = Label(root, text = 'Size')
Label_size_b = Label(root, text = '---')
Label_size_a.place(x = 700, y = 195)
Label_size_b.place(x = 750, y = 195)


Button_save = Button(root, text = 'Save', command = save)
Button_load = Button(root, text = 'Load', command = load)
Button_size_add = Button(root, text = 'Upgrade', command = change_size)
Button_save.place(x = 700, y = 500)
Button_load.place(x = 750, y = 500)
Button_size_add.place(x = 800, y = 225)
```

At first, I called change_size() and save(),

it printed "[3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [151, 1, 1, 1, 1]]"

and the label[Label_size_b] had showed the change in size(it printed "151) and it is saved.

However when I restart the module and call load(), it still print the data above  "[3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [151, 1, 1, 1, 1]]" .

But the main problem is label[Label_size_b] is printed as "1" but not "151"
that mean I changed something and load it, but the Label still print the Original data!(see the top on code)

I guess it may be the "global" problem but I can't find any way to correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line in the `load()` function:

```
Label_size_b.configure(text = Prvs_size[0])
```

Here `Prvs_size` refers to the global variable that is initialised to `[1,1,1,1,1]` when the script starts, and is never updated. You need to access the values loaded from the pickle file into `GameData` like this:

```
Label_size_b.configure(text = GameData[1][0])
```

This accesses the first element of the second list in the `GameData` list as loaded from the pickled data.

There is a similar problem in the `change_size()` function.

Comment: @Montague27: not sure if you noticed my last update, but there's a similar problem in `change_size()`.

Comment: Yes, I knew it. :D